# Load a specific php page

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to make wordpress load a specific static php file(not a page template) for wordpress pages.

For example, for the contact page i would like to load the already done contact.php.

I tried adding in functions.php something like:

```
if( is_page('careers')){
    get_page('careers.php');
}
```

or

```
function get_pages() {
     if(is_page('careers')) {
          return get_template_uri() . '/careers.php';
     }
 }
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: I've managed to load the pages by renaming them to page-careers.php, page-contact.php, and so on.
I tried your solutions but I had no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get template part is usually used for retrieving template files like you are trying to do. See more here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

So, for example in your code above, if you had a file called contact.php in your theme folder that you wanted to include, you could use the following code:

```
get_template_part( 'contact' );
```

Answer (score 3):

**Try this for include PHP file**

```
<?php include(ABSPATH . "banner.php"); ?>
```

**And get another page content**

```
$my_id = 5369;
$post_id_5369 = get_post($my_id);
$content = $post_id_5369->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $content);
echo $content;
```